# Where is stable cardapio?

Tags: menu, cardapio

I try to install cardapio but i saw tha is unstable. Is any stable release and if not when wil be stable. In cardapio launchpad theres is not any schedule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, I am one of the Cardapio developers. :)

The current »unstable« PPA can be considered stable. It is just named unstable because there is no definitive 1.0 release yet.

There is no release schedule because we have none. Version 1 will be ready when it is ready but as I said, Cardapio is safe to install right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/unstable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cardapio
```

Using Cardapio

To use as a panel applet, simply add it as usualRight-click the panel, select “Add to panel”, then choose “Cardapio”.

more information and screenshot https://launchpad.net/cardapio

Comment: read question again, more accurately

Answer (score 0):

You better ask this to the [Cardapio developers](https://launchpad.net/~cardapio-team/+contactuser) or on the [Cardapio help forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/cardapio).

How to find this next time you have such a question?

On the [Cardapio overview page](https://launchpad.net/cardapio), below the project description, you will find a link to the maintainers of the project, the [Cardapio team](https://launchpad.net/~cardapio-team).  On the Cardapio team page you can see a "Contact this team's owner" button on the right side.

Also on the Cardapio overview page, at the top you can find an "Answers" tab, which brings you to the help forum.